# Get the view a UIButton is on

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a UIButton on a Custom UITableViewCell, i have a method "done".

How can i get the CustomTableViewCell via the Button?

```
-(IBAction)done:(id)sender {
    (CustmCell((UIButton)sender).viewTheButtonIsOn...).action
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer by CodaFi is most likely enough but it does make the assumption that the button is added directly to the table cell. A slightly more complicated but safer bit of code could be something like:

```
-(IBAction)done:(id)sender {
    UIView *parent = [sender superview];
    while (parent && ![parent isKindOfClass:[CustomCell class]]) {
        parent = parent.superview;
    }

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)parent;
    [cell someAction];
}
```

Comment: You dastard!  Excellent use of strong-ish typing in a loop. ++

Answer (score 5):

If it is added directly to the cell as a subview, you can use `-superview` to get it's parent view.  Also, you need to cast with pointers because objects are never taken by value, only pointed to in Objective-C.

```
-(IBAction)done:(id)sender {
    [(CustmCell*)[(UIButton*)sender superview]someAction];
}
```

Comment: If the button was added to the cell's `contentView` you will need two calls to `superview`.

Comment: Exactly.  You can keep calling superview on superview over and over again until you reach it's parent view.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to create a subclass of UIButton that has a CustomCell property, to access the CustomCell object directly.  This is technically better code than looking for superviews of superviews.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to think about the contentView also, or any other subview of the cell the button may be contained in now or in the future. Be safe and traverse the parent hierarchy.

```
var parent = button.superview
while let v = parent where !v.isKindOfClass(MyCustomCell)   {
    parent = v.superview
}

// parent is now your MyCustomeCell object
```